# Nodejs v8.6.0 getting warning: [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am learning node, and in the program below I am getting the warning stating:

> "(node:93236) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous
>   function without callback is
>   deprecated."(https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0013_fs_asynchronous_function_without_callback)

script:

```
var fs = require('fs');


fs.open('test.txt', 'r', function (err, handle) {
    if (err == null) {
        var f = handle;
        var b = new Buffer(100000);

        fs.read(f, b, 0, 100000, null, function (err, bytes_read) {
            if (err == null) {
                console.log(b.toString("utf8", 0, bytes_read));
            } else {
                console.log("Oh Noes! fail on read: " + err.code + " " + err.message);
            }
            fs.close(f);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Oh noes! fail an open: " + err.code + " " + err.message);
    }
});
```

How should I proceed in order to find how a callback function should be properly included in these functions fs.open(...) and fs.read(...)?
Thanks!

Comment: [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback) appears to take a callback as well

Comment: @Bergi is correct.  the call should be `fs.close(f, function() {})` to resolve the warning

Comment: Thanks @Bergi Issue resolved!